# Can Java JSON Parsers hit remote services?

Tags: java, json, web-services

I am wondering if I can use Java JSON Frameworks (Such as Jackson, Google GSON or JSON.simple) to read JSON from a different server.

I have a web services server that I want to hit to receive JSON and then turn that JSON into a Java object. Currently the only way I know how to do that is to use jQuery to hit the server, get the JSON back and then post that to a java utility. It would be a great shortcut to effectively "cURL" the other server so I can eliminate an ajax call.

I have only seen local file examples for these frameworks.

Comment: Why does the parser need to do this? It's just a parser. Retrieve the string to parse in some other way, like using [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) for example..

Comment: The parser doesn't have to do anything, but if it reads out of a file it could read out of a url and eliminate a step. I didn't say why doesn't it do this? It should. I asked if it did, because if that's a feature it would truly be dumb to use URL first when you could just use the parser.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet downloads whatever is at the specified URL to string `result`. You can then process the string using the usual JSON parsers.

```
URL url = new URL("http://the.address.i.want");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String inputLine, result = "";
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // System.out.println(inputLine);
    result += inputLine + "\n";
}
in.close();
```

Comment: Great solution, I hadn't thought of that. Still interested to see if those frameworks support the remote reading though.